# Check if enum class contains a specific identfier

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14, enum-class

I searched a bit here on SO and was surprise that I didn't find any similar question. Happy for any hints in case this has already been answered.

I have a codebase with a lot of enum classes defined. Some of them specify a totalNum constant like

```
enum class Foo : int
{
    a,
    b,
    c,

    totalNum
}
```

Others don't have this like

```
enum class Bar : bool
{
    oneOption,
    otherOption
}
```

Then I have a function basically like this

```
template <class EnumClassType>
EnumClassType typeToEnum (typename std::underlying_type<EnumClassType>::type value)
{
    // If you hit this assertion, the value is outside of the valid enum range
    assert (isPositiveAndBelow (value, decltype (value) (EnumClassType::totalNum)));

    return EnumClassType (value);
}
```

While this works and makes sense for the an enum with `totalNum` specified, I'd like to skip this assert in case there is no such identifier in the enum. Is there any way to do that? The codebase is currently using C++ 14 but C++ 17 solutions are also welcome due to an upcoming compiler change.

Comment: You can use SFINAE to [provide an overload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/templated-check-for-the-existence-of-a-class-member-function) where if an item is an `enum` and has `::totalNum` it then does the static assert.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer myself in the meantime, using an approach like @jfh mentioned in the comments.

First of all this is a way to check if an enum class contains an identifier with a certain name

```
template <class EnumToTest>
class EnumConstantDefined_totalNum
{
private:
    using Yes = int8_t;
    using No = int16_t;

    template <class E>
    static Yes test (decltype (E::totalNum)*);

    template <class E>
    static No test (...);

public:
    static constexpr bool value = sizeof (test<EnumToTest> (0)) == sizeof (Yes);
};
```

Then we can employ SFINAE to specify two overloads for both kinds of enums.

```
template <class EnumType>
std::enable_if_t<EnumConstantDefined_totalNum<EnumType>::value, void> assertValueIsInRange (typename std::underlying_type<EnumType>::type value)
{
    assert (isPositiveAndBelow (value, decltype (value) (EnumType::totalNum)));
}

template <class EnumType>
std::enable_if_t<! EnumConstantDefined_totalNum<EnumType>::value, void> assertValueIsInRange (typename std::underlying_type<EnumType>::type)
{
    // do nothing
}
```

Then use this assertion function in the actual conversion function

```
/**
   Casts a value matching an enum class underlying type to an enum class constant and asserts that the
   value is inside the valid enum range
 */
template <class EnumClassType>
EnumClassType typeToEnum (typename std::underlying_type<EnumClassType>::type value)
{
    assertValueIsInRange<EnumClassType> (value);

    return EnumClassType (value);
}
```

Comment: Beat me by 15s. ;-)